# illumination problem for face landmark detection

Tags: image-recognition, image-preprocessing, opencv

I trained dlib face landmark detection model using ibug and yaleB datasets. Accuracy of the model is dropping when a bright light or a shadow appears on the side face. Used default parameters and similar images were included while training. Is there any solution to overcome the problem.

[image: sample results of the model]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you might try out the brightness data augmentation; in Keras you have something like:

```
ImageDataGenerator(brightness_range=[0.2,1.0])
```

in case you want to generate different brightness levels between 20% and 100% based on your train images. For example (taken from *Deep learning for computer vision* book by Jason Brownlee):

[image]

Comment: I increased brightness but no improvement when I'm applying brightness correction to images losing features (like face is not found by detection model)
it would be better to apply an image processing technique while testing, I'm losing accuracy with those lighting conditions. Is there any image processing technique that would help me.

Comment: Maybe you can also try other data augmentation techniques like zoom?